# Encrypting text with AES and MPC

Tags: aes, secret-sharing, multiparty-computation, garbled-circuits

I'm thinking of implementing text encryption and decryption in my program using AES using key sharing thanks to MPC (the point is that the key should never be provided in full), however, all public libraries that I found offer this option only assuming that one member has the whole key and another plaintext. Does anyone know libraries that allow you to implement such a solution?

Comment: Please clarify the question; what kind of answer you are looking for? "Has anyone dealt with a similar problem?" is not what you're after, right?

Comment: Cross-posted with Information Security [Encrypting text with AES and MPC](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/227090/86735). This not a good ethic in SO. Please delete one.

Comment: Note that requests for software libraries are off-topic. However asking which protocol would be best for the problem would be fully on-topic.

Comment: You may also want to read [this help center page](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts.

Comment: I've answered a similar question here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/61175/aes-encryption-using-mpc-spdz-protocol?rq=1